# UITableView does not show the cells.

Tags: uitableview, swift, xcode6.1

I have implemented in my project with CocoaPods RESideMenu and I created a view that contains the table then. My problem is that the table does not make me see the cells, xcode me no mistakes and then not know where I'm wrong. Can anyone help? I enter the code:

```
import UIKit

class RightMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate {

var tableView = UITableView()
var titles = ["Home","Profilo","Notizie","Impostazioni"]
//var images = ["IconHome","IconCalendar","IconProfile","IconSettings","IconEmpty"]

init(frame: CGRect, dialStrings: [String]) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, (frame.size.height - 54 * 2) / 2.0, frame.size.width, 54 * 2), style:UITableViewStyle.Plain)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0, 0, 0)
        //contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.opaque = false
    self.tableView.bounces = false
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil //UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "BackMenu"))
    self.tableView.scrollsToTop = false
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    view.addSubview(self.tableView)


}



required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 54.0
}


 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return titles.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        cell!.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 21)
        cell!.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        cell!.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell!.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.alloc()

    }
        return cell!
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    var salViewController: UIViewController
    switch (indexPath.row){
    case 0:
        salViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as UIViewController
        break
    case 1:
        salViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profilo") as UIViewController
        break
    case 2:
        salViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Notizie") as UIViewController
        break
    case 3:
        salViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Impostazioni") as UIViewController
        break
    default:
        break

    }

}

}
```

Comment: So, in numberOfRows, NSLog `titles.count`.

Comment: Check the storyboard is the TableViewController being presented by the storyboard? Is your custom RightMenuViewController the Class on the Identity Inspector Alt+Cmd+3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enter this line of code will not see otherwise never your Array Titles:

```
cell!.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
```

once inserted properly will see the menu.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem is in the below line.**

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CELL")
```

This will create a cell using identifier "Cell" in reuse queue so that when you write code like below

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        cell!.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 21)
        cell!.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        cell!.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell!.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView.alloc()    
    }
```

**cell will never nil**
Remove that line and all works perfect


[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

[image]

Comment: I deleted the part of code indicated, however, does not make me see the contents of the cells so the array shown above is displayed. I'm thinking that this is a mistake of the libraries RESideMenu.

Comment: @RoxyS There may be no problem in RESideMenu i debug the code and sure that problem because you use "registerClass".

Comment: @RoxyS did you day that above code did not help you to make cell? if that the case i have to delete my answer,

Comment: Basically I had not put the menu item of the label, in fact entering the code of the answer above, I see the contents of the label so the menu items ..... I had to delete the entry registerClass anyway .... thanks anyway for the 'help.

Answer (score 0):

In `func tableView(...)`, you never assign any data to your cells. It makes sense that they're blank.